# How to create dynamic meteor js buttons that will sync with whatever Collection is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

My app has a **list** of products which can be **sorted with buttons** based on **id** (which is determined by their product type or class, see below).

```
<template name="filterbuttons">

  <div class="filter-button-container">
      <button id="foo" type="submit" name="foo">Foo</button>
      <button id="bar" type="submit" name="bar">Bar</button>
```

Sometimes the user will navigate to a different class of products, and I need update the buttons to reflect this.

```
<template name="filterbuttons">

      <div class="filter-button-container">
          {{#each product }}
          <button id="{{ product.type }}" type="submit" name="{{ product.type }}">{{ product.type }}</button>
```

Now the catch. My list contains duplicates, so I also have to loop through and pick out only unique `product.type` values. Is there a handy way to do this with the templates (Meteor Blaze)?  Or does that require a helper, like...

```
Template.filterbuttons.helpers({
  product: function () {
    // ... 
    // use _.uniq() to remove duplicates

    return {type: {['foo', 'bar']}}

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but according to [this](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-weekly-meteor-09-rc-meteor-new-logo-underscore-in-templates.html), Meteor 0.9 allows you to use underscore in your templates.

> Now you can use underscore directly inside Blaze templates. It’s a result of a very simple package by Gwendall Esnault. It’s a handy utility.

[Underscore Helper](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-underscore-helper) is the package MeteorHacks is referring to.